# Does Pyspark `array` function preserve order?

Tags: arrays, pyspark

Does array function `pyspark.sql.functions.array(*cols)` keep order in creating an array from `cols`?

As an example, if my dataframe is

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|
|   2|   4|   6|
|   7|   2|   4|
+----+----+----+
```

Should I always expect it preserves the order in output array?

```
df.withColumn('col4', F.array('col1', 'col2', 'col3')).show()
+----+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|col3|     col4|
+----+----+----+---------+
|   1|   2|   3|[1, 2, 3]|
|   2|   4|   6|[2, 4, 6]|
|   7|   2|   4|[7, 2, 4]|
+----+----+----+---------+
```

Or it might change order of `cols` in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are creating array, it will not change Order. Order will be same in all case. It will keep same order like `col1, col2, col3`. It is totally depend on the order you use during array creation. It will not change means first value of `col4` in your dataframe will be `[1, 2, 3]`, it will be never like `[1, 3, 2]` or `[3, 2, 1]`.

But if your concern is about vertically order (row wise) then it might change as per partition data. That you can manage by using `SortBy`, `ParitionBy` to preserve same order.